# Transferring a Windows Service to another computer using the installer

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a C# Windows Service on my desktop and I want to transfer the service using the installer to another computer. I placed the service/installer on my flash drive and attempted to install it on the other machine. It installed correctly but would not start successfully. Does anyone have a clue as to why it may be doing this??

I am using VS 2010.

Comment: Look in the event logs for possible reasons it fails to start.  I expect this is more for something like the superuser group, though.

Comment: You'll need to include some errors/logs.  Check the event log on the machine where it doesn't work.  "not starting" can be any of a million things

Comment: I figured out what it was. My service listened on my ip address at specific port...and I didn't change it for that service... Thanks alot! Log is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Is the correct .Net framework installed on the destination machine? 
Are any dependent files missing?
Any there ant hard coded paths or directories missing?
Is it running under the correct account with the correct permissions?

Comment: yes. it is another development machine like mine with VS 2010 on it. I believe everything should be there. I created the installer using the designer and followed the steps as seen [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx [/link]. Do you know whether or not I can just copy the installer or must I copy other things too?